# Deprecation Warnings in THREE.js and WebGL - "encodings_fragment" and texSubImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am working on a WebGL-based project using THREE.js, and I recently started receiving the following deprecation warnings in the browser console:

1. THREE.WebGLRenderer: Shader chunk 'encodings_fragment' has been deprecated. Use 'colorspace_fragment' instead."
2. WebGL warning: texSubImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads.

I would like to understand the implications of these deprecation warnings and how I can resolve them. What changes do I need to make to my code to replace 'encodings_fragment' with 'colorspace_fragment' in THREE.js shaders? Additionally, how can I address the deprecation of 'Alpha-premult' and 'y-flip' in my texSubImage calls to prevent these warnings from appearing?

1. Checked the official THREE.js documentation and release notes for information regarding these deprecation warnings, but didn't find any specific details on how to handle them.
2. Reviewed my WebGL and THREE.js shader code to see if I was using 'encodings_fragment' in any custom shaders but couldn't find any instances.
3. Reviewed the texSubImage calls in my code to understand how the 'Alpha-premult' and 'y-flip' settings are being used, but it seems to be related to uploading non-DOM-Element images to textures.

I would appreciate understanding the reason behind these deprecation warnings and how to address them properly in my code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing are your code as a live example (https://jsfiddle.net/g3atw6k5/) so is possible to debug both warnings?

Comment: Sure, but Iam unable to find a service that allows you to make the repository public. In that case, I have set up an invitation link on CodeSandbox for you to access the project.You can find it here: codesandbox.io/invite/cfpx7gxzxq69sqsx. This will allow you to review the code. Once you've clicked the link and entered the team dashboard, please proceed to the "repos" section and select "Awadhila/Myshirt-project draft/festive-dawn." With this repository, the server will start automatically. Thank you for your understanding, and I look forward to your help! 